# How to append the elements from array to container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am getting json objects from backend by shuffled. when It reach front end, i am looping the object and placing to array by it's id value. **so I re-sorted them properly.** But I am not able to append the elements what i save to array.

here is my example:

HTML : `<div id="selectors"></div>`

```
var object = [
    {"name":"name4", "id" : 4},
    {"name":"name1", "id" : 1},
    {"name":"name3", "id" : 3},
    {"name":"name2", "id" : 2}
    ]

var elements = [];

$.each(object,function(index, obj){
    var num  = parseInt(obj.id)
                elements[num] = $('<select></select>', {'id':num});
});

$('#selectors').append($(elements));
```

Any one suggest me the correct approach or tell me the best way.

[Here is the Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/8UKgr/)

I am looking the output should be :

```
<div id="selectors">
<select id="1"></select><select id="2"></select><select id="3"></select><select id="4"></select>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be best of using `map()`, which returns jQuery objects anyway. You can then go on to `sort()` your select boxes, by their `id`s:

```
var elements = $.map(object, function(v){
    return $('<select></select>', {'id':parseInt(v.id)});
}).sort(function(a,b){
    return a.prop('id') > b.prop('id');
});

$('#selectors').append(elements);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8UKgr/7/)

Comment: +1 for short and sweet. You can reduce it to `$('<select>', {'id':parseInt(v.id)});` as an element close is not required.

Answer (score 0):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/8UKgr/1/

Use an empty jQuery object/collection `$()` and add elements to it.

```
var elements = $();

$.each(object,function(index, obj){
    var num  = parseInt(obj.id)
    elements = elements.add($('<select></select>', {'id':num}));
});

$('#selectors').append(elements);
```

### Update (+ sorting): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/8UKgr/6/

Uses jQuery `sortElements` extension from here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

```
$('#selectors').append(elements);
elements.sortElements(function (o1, o2) {
    return o1.id >= o2.id ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: Remember the radix. Even though it's already a number in the posted code.

Comment: @David Thomas: They are hard-wired and do not have leading 0's, so not an issue. If the server spat out leading 0's I would be very suprised :)

Comment: the elements is not sorted properly. i need to append the elements by it's id. so the html will be id='1', 2, 3 like so...

Comment: the issue is, i need to append the element by it's serial. otherwise it will cause the user according to my app.

Comment: @oGeez: If you need to pre-sort, before append, go with `oGeez`'s map answer. By default the map should be sorted by key. To get mine to do that the `$()` would need to be a dummy element with appends, then sort, then append to display (mine has too much overhead now) :)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$.each(object,function(index, obj){
    var num  = parseInt(obj.id)

    $('#selectors').append($('<select />').attr('id',num));
});
```

you can check it here ..http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/8UKgr/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want sorted array. So for this first sort `object` array using jquery `.sort()`.

```
object = object.sort(function (a, b) {  if (a.id< b.id) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a.id> b.id) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; });
```

And then get the array items one by one using `.each()`

Try this following code:

```
var object = [
    {"name":"name4", "id" : 4},
    {"name":"name1", "id" : 1},
    {"name":"name3", "id" : 3},
    {"name":"name2", "id" : 2}
    ]

object = object.sort(function (a, b) { return a.id >= b.id ? 1 : -1; });

var elements = $();
$.each(object,function(index, obj){    
 $('#selectors').append($('<select></select>', {'id':obj.id}));
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8UKgr/9/)

Or you can also use HTML Elements Object Collection. Create an empty collection `$()`.

```
var object = [
    {"name":"name4", "id" : 4},
    {"name":"name1", "id" : 1},
    {"name":"name3", "id" : 3},
    {"name":"name2", "id" : 2}
    ]

object = object.sort(function (a, b) { return a.id >= b.id ? 1 : -1; });

var elements = $();
$.each(object,function(index, obj){    
    elements = elements.add($('<select></select>', {'id':obj.id}));
});
$('#selectors').append($(elements));
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8UKgr/10/)

Comment: this is the solution. but this is very long coding to achieve this.

Comment: @3gwebtrain: Please see updated answer. Yes you are right it's long code but I think, it's the simplest way to achieve your task. ("TrueBlueAussie" also suggest a way to do this please see.)

Answer (score 0):

Or this...

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

object
.sort(function(a,b){return a.id > b.id})
.map(function(el){
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.id = el.id;
    fragment.appendChild(select);
});

$('#selectors').append(fragment);
```

more code but better performance.
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xk4f3/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
var object = [
    {"name":"name4", "id" : 4},
    {"name":"name1", "id" : 1},
    {"name":"name3", "id" : 3},
    {"name":"name2", "id" : 2}
    ]

var elements = [];
object.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
    // Ascending: first id less than the previous
    return obj1.id - obj2.id;
});

var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#selectors');
$.each(object, function(i, option){

 sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',option.id).text(option.name));
});
```

Check this link : http://jsfiddle.net/8UKgr/11/